# Get URL from string with text

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of strings like this:

```
Some text, bla-bla http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=51e5a300e4b084575d8568bb#.UeWjBcCzaaA.twitter
```

And I need to parse this String to two:

```
Some text, bla-bla

http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=51e5a300e4b084575d8568bb#.UeWjBcCzaaA.twitter
```

I need separate them, but, of course, it's enough to parse only URL.

Can you help me, how can I parse url from string like this.

Comment: Split before `http:...`?

Comment: Did you do any research of your own before asking here? I just googled "extract url from string" and there are a lot of posts that may be helpful that came up! :)

Comment: You might be looking for a [URL regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    String string = "sometext http://www.something.com";
    String url = string.substring(string.indexOf("http"), string.length());
    System.out.println(url);
```

or use split.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how robust you want your parser to be.  If you can reasonably expect every url to start with http://, then you can use

```
  string.indexOf("http://");
```

This returns the index of the first character of the string you pass in (and -1 if the string does not appear).

Full code to return a substring with just the URL:

```
  string.substring(string.indexOf("http://"));
```

Here's the documentation for Java's String class.  Let this become your friend in programming! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

By using `split` :

```
    String str = "Some text, bla-bla http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=51e5a300e4b084575d8568bb#.UeWjBcCzaaA.twitter";
    String [] ar = str.split("http\\.*");
    System.out.println(ar[0]);
    System.out.println("http"+ar[1]);
```

Comment: just want to post,but you did that:)

Answer (score -2):

I know in PHP you'd be able to run the explode() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. You'd choose which character you want to explode at. For instance, you could explode at "http://"

So running the code via PHP would look like:

```
$string  = "Some text, bla-bla http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=51e5a300e4b084575d8568bb#.UeWjBcCzaaA.twitter";
$pieces = explode("http://", $string);
echo $pieces[0]; // Would print "Some text, bla-bla"
echo $pieces[1]; // Would print "www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=51e5a300e4b084575d8568bb#.UeWjBcCzaaA.twitter"
```